# ode45 error, index out of bounds because numel(x)=1

Tags: matlab, ode

```
    function xx = test(x, t)


   xx(1) = x(2);
   xx(2) = x(3) * cos(x(4) + x(1));
   xx(3) = 0;
   xx(4) = 0;

end
```

That is my script, confused as to why I am getting this error.

Comment: `xx` is your output?  may be you meant `xx(1) = x(2);` etc.. also better to preallocate `xx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side given to the [ODE suites](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) pass the arguments as `(t,x)` where `t` is always scalar.
So your function signature should be

```
function xx = test(t,x)
```

Comment: that did it, I was adapting this script from an octave one where everything is reversed and missed that one. thank you. how can i get this to return a column vector?

Comment: @excelhelp You need to explicitly allocate it as such: `xx(4,1) = 0`.  Then all references with single indices will reference the rows of the column vector.

Comment: will give it a shot thank you. who knew going from lsode to ode45 would be such a hassle.